# This program repeats in the console

Tags: java

I'm making this program that lists websites, username, and password data (kind of like a passwords manager), and in the console I get this:
[Select: Not a valid entry! repeats twice](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SIunH.png)

I'm not sure why this is happening, but here is the code block:

```
    System.out.print("PASSCODE: ");
    passcode = (char) System.in.read();
    if(passcode == '}'){
        System.out.println("Welcome! Enter 'Q' to exit at any time!");
        System.out.println("1) Website A \n2) Website B \n3) Website C \n4) Website D");
        for(;(char) choice != 'Q';){
            System.out.print("SELECT: ");
            choice = (char) System.in.read();
            switch(choice){
                case '1':
                    websiteA.Display();
                    break;
                case '2':
                    websiteB.Display();
                    break;
                case '3':
                    websiteC.Display();
                    break;
                case '4':
                    websiteD.Display();
                    break;
                default:
                    System.out.println("\nNot a valid entry!");
            }
        }
    } else {System.out.println("ACCESS DENIED");}
```

I'm confused, because I would think the code would halt at System.in.read() in the for loop.
Aside from the objects, everything here is a conglomeration of what I've learned up to chapter 3 from Java: A Beginner's Guide Eight Edition by Herbert Schildt. So I'm still somewhat new to this.

Comment: you should use `while(choice != 'Q')` instead of for loop

Answer (score 0):

When you enter a char, there's actually 2 char sent, the first one is your key, the second is the `line break` char code, aka `\n`. So with the loop, it will process twice for each choice.